# coloring functions in Matlab script: native vs. custom functions?

Tags: matlab, function, colors, native

Is it possible to show functions in a Matlab script, such that 'built-in' functions appear in one color, and custom functions (home-grown) appear in another color?

```
histc % appears in 'green'

myOwnFxn % appears in 'purple'
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no way easy way to distinguish between builtin and user defined functions programatically. You can change the [colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) before calling each function which may help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to apply a specific color to function names. If you head to `Preferences -> Colors -> Programming Tools` and to `Preferences -> Editor/Debugger` you can pretty much discover by yourself what can be customized and what cannot be customized.

On the top of that, there is the problem of distinguishing between build-in functions and a used-defined functions, which is very hard to solve programmatically and nobody knows if the syntax highlighting framework of Matlab can handle such distinction.

Of course, language syntaxes must be defined somewhere inside the Matlab package. Finding them, learning how to manipulate them (if possible) and forcing Matlab to accept a new one can be very time consuming. If you plan to break the rules and do some reverse engineering to analyze the feasibility of your task, I wish you all the best.